# terraform module reference looking for optional sku variable in azurerm_automation_account

Tags: azure, terraform

Terraform should run fine. But, throws error that "sku" is not set for azurerm_automation_account for the "sku", which is optional for the resource.

```
    > agent/main.tf

    module "security" {
    source = "../security"
    env = "${var.env}"
    location = "${var.location}"
    }

    > security/main.tf

    resource "azurerm_automation_account" "aut_acc" {

    depends_on = ["azurerm_storage_blob.blobobject"]
    name = "GAV-ARV-${var.env}-AUT-ACC-01"
    location = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg_aut.location}"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg_aut.name}"
    }

    > security/var.tf

    variable "env" {
    description = "The env being deployed to (dev, qa, stg, prd)"
    default = "dev"
    }
    variable "location" {
    description = "The location of the resources being created"
    default = "westus"
    }
```

Comment: When i run "terraform plan", getting the following error

Error: module.agent.module.security.azurerm_automation_account.aut_acc: "sku": required field is not set

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full error (looks like you have it in the comment above) and also show your Terraform versions (the core and provider versions can be found by running `terraform -version` on an `init`'ed directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in azurerm provider version 1.29.0 of terraform. After updating the version to 1.32.0, it got fixed and there is no exception thrown for optional parameters.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "=1.32.0"
  subscription_id = "${var.subscription}"
  client_id       = "${var.service_principal_name}"
  client_secret   = "${var.service_principal_secret}"
  tenant_id       = "${var.tenantId}"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about that?! I did the test in 1.32.0 version and it also shows the error. Do you apply it?

Comment: Yes, after upgrading the version, i didn't get errors related to optional parameters. This is the solution for this.

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of the result that you successfully apply the terraform?

Comment: It actually solved my problem with another optional variable! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It shows the property `sku` should be an optional parameter, but actually, it's a required parameter according to my test. And additional, the `sku` will be deprecated. So I suggest you use the parameter `sku_name`. The support value are "Basic" and "Free". So the block should like below:

```
resource "azurerm_automation_account" "aut_acc" {

depends_on = ["azurerm_storage_blob.blobobject"]
name = "GAV-ARV-${var.env}-AUT-ACC-01"
location = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg_aut.location}"
resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg_aut.name}"

sku_name = "Basic"   # or "Free"
}
```

Note: As I see, the depends_on is not necessary for the automation account.